# Perlomeno, perlopiù, quantomeno, suppergiù etc

Tags: phrase-request

Esistono una serie di espressioni in italiano che possono essere scritte in  un unica parola o staccate nelle diverse parole da cui sono composte, ad esempio:

> Anzitempo, 
>   Anzi tempo
>
> Anzitutto, 
>   Anzi tutto
>
> Casomai, 
>   Caso mai
>
> Ciononostante, 
>   Ciò nonostante
>
> Controvoglia, 
>   Contro voglia
>
> Dappertutto, 
>   Da per tutto
>
> Dappoco, 
>   Da poco

La forma originale di queste espressioni sembra essere quella staccata, l'uso ripetuto ha poi probabilmente generato le forma in un unico termine.

Ad esempio da quanto risulta da [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=per%20lo%20meno%2Cperlomeno&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cper%20lo%20meno%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cperlomeno%3B%2Cc0) la forma attaccata di  *perlomeno* si è  diffusa successivamente a quella staccata.

Qual è il termine per definire questo tipo di fenomeno linguistico?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

È il fenomeno dell'[**univerbazione**](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/univerbazione_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/):

> L’*univerbazione* è il risultato di un processo diacronico che conduce alla «[f]usione – manifestata anche dalla grafia – di due parole originariamente autonome (*palco scenico* - *palcoscenico*, *in vece* - *invece*, ecc.)» (Serianni 1989: 750). Come si vede anche dagli esempi riportati, l’univerbazione riguarda casi molto diversi tra loro, che includono sintagmi preposizionali (come *almeno* o *invece*) e altre unità di origine sintattica (*tuttavia*, *malaria*, *nontiscordardimé*, ecc.).

Un caso particolare è la *concrezione* o *agglutinazione*, «di una parola, in genere di carattere grammaticale, con un’altra di carattere lessicale», dove la prima può essere un prefisso (come “-mente” per gli avverbi), un articolo etc.

Comment: Interessante grazie, immagino che il fenomeno della de-univerbalizzazione non esista, o perlomeno non in modo significativo.

Comment: Non mi viene in mente un fenomeno generale, ma qualcosa di interessante lo puoi trovare qui: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/rianalisi_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano) , in particolare ai punti c) e d).